# Install Root CA Certificate to SLES 12

Tags: linux, ssl, certificate, suse, trusted-root-ca

I want to add my SLES 12 server to our SUSE subscription to get updates. When I run the SUSEConnect command with necessary parameters, the server returns an error to me like this:

```
SSL verification failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain
Certificate issuer: /CN=Mycompany Root CA SHA256
Certificate subject: /CN=Mycompany Root CA SHA256
SUSEConnect error: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
```

I have 2 files for root ca certificate. One of them is MycompanyRootCA.cer and the other one is MycompanyIssuingRootCA.cer. But I don't know how can I import these 2 files to register my system to SUSE. I cannnot find a solution (not workaround) on internet. How can I fix this SSL problem with these files?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue on a SLE-15-SP1 machine. In my case it seems like the hardware clock was the problem, it was set to a date in 2019. Setting it to a current date and registering with yast fixed it for me.